# Which is the best tool to monitor replication on MySQL 5.5.20?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I have just installed and setup replication for 3 MySQL 5.5.20 server( 1 Master/ 2 slaves). I intend to add more slaves to the equation.

Which is the best software tool to monitor the replication status ( like `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;`)

Also i want to know, how much is the replication lagging in time and error reports if there is any error in replication.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can refer this link as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518811/mysql-replication-monitoring-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Percona toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/). Look at pt-heartbeat, and some of their other tools as well.